# Need to make a script that will use a password protected file and generate an output

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I am designing a Lab for a course at university.For this the students will download a folder called LAB1 and this will contain subfolders called author_solution ,student_solution and evaluate.sh file.The author_solution is a password protected folder which contains the solution and it should not be accessible to the students.The students will put their solution in the student_solution folder.Now, to evaluate the lab , they need to run evaluate.sh in terminal which will output their score.I was wondering how to achieve this requirement.

What I tried to do was change the  access permission of author_solution to be accessible only by root using "chmod 000 author_solution".But the problem with this is,when they run evaluate.sh, terminal will ask for root password, and this is not known by the students , so I have to personally go to every student's system and enter the password.

So,is there a way using which the student can run evaluate.sh in terminal by themselves without the terminal asking them for a password(By which my intervention to enter the password every time will not be required).

PS:The operating system in Ubuntu 16.04.
Any help is appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: You should ask on U&L stack or askubuntu

Answer (score 1):

> By which my intervention to enter the password every time will not be required

- Start with a small test by entering some invalid password, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and check the error message you get. Let's assume it says "Password is incorrect".
- Set the password to `incorrect`.
- Have your student do there thing, and tell them to carefully follow the instructions on the screen, especially if they have problems with passwords. If they are able to read, and follow the instructions, they should not need any intervention from you to enter the password ...